# cvCvtColor crashes when converting from RGB to grayscale

Tags: c, opencv

I'm trying to convert an image from RGB to grayscale.  However, I am getting this error when trying:

> OpenCV Error: Null pointer  in unknown
>   function, file
>   ......\ocv\opencv\src\cxcore\cxarray.cpp,
>   line 2376

Why might this be happening?

Comment: Please post your source and the full stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error, later discovered that the Iplimage I was getting as the source was null.
try putting breakpoints and check whether the src image(CvArray) is not null.
and do create a dst image by cvCreateImage()

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure img and bw_img is a valid pointer, and not NULL by any chance?

The destination image must exist - it's not created by cvtColor() otherwise you would have to pass a pointer to a pointer.

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/miscellaneous_image_transformations.html#cvtcolor
"dst – The destination image of the same data type as the source. The number of channels may be different"

Comment: img is positively valid.  bw_img is declared in the code given above.  Unless there is something wrong with that...

Answer (score -1):

Notice the following:

> ..The destination image of the **same data type as the source**.

Otherwise, you'll crash.